# Open a calendar from a widget app

Tags: android, calendar

I want to open a calendar (for instance, google calendar) from my widget app. I did something like that:

```
    Intent intent2 = new Intent();
    //Froyo or greater 
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.google.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");
    intent2.setComponent(cn);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
            intent2, 0);

    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.calendar, pendingIntent2);
```

But it doesn´t work. Any help?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works:

```
    Intent intent2 = new Intent();
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.calendar",
            "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");
    intent2.setComponent(cn);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
            intent2, 0);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.calendar, pendingIntent2);
```

and in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity">
    </activity>
```